# How to increase voltage drop across LED?

Tags: led, infrared

Hi I am using LED of 1550nm(Datasheet Link Attached) thorlabs.and voltage drop which I am getting across it is 0.866V. I have connected a 60ohm resistor in series and voltage which I've provided is 5V.

How can I get the rated voltage value?[LED155E Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=LED1550E)

Comment: Please supply a link to the datasheet for your specific LED

Comment: There is no optimal value - the volt drop is what it is by YOUR design.

Comment: What is the optimal current for this device? You are sending about 70mA through it with these values.

Comment: Instead of concentrating on the **voltage drop** concentrate on the **current** through the LED. The datasheet will specify what current you need.

Comment: cooling will reduce the wavelength and increasethe voltage, dunk it in liquid nitrogen.

Comment: There's something wrong with your LED or your circuit. The datasheet says that the forward drop at 20mA should be about 1.5V. Since you seem to be supplying more on the order of 60 mA, the voltage drop should be somewhat higher, but in any case no less.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that current for "optimal" LED operation is 100 mA. Than from the datasheet you find out that voltage for this current is 1V. Then the resistor you need to meet this conditions is \$ R = \frac{5V - 1V}{100 mA} = 40 \Omega\$. Hope this helps.